# Read PDF files using Grails

Tags: web-applications, grails

I want to parse PDF files from websites.

Can anyone say how to extract text (word by word) from a PDF file using Grails?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know in Grails / Groovy but you can use the Apache lib [PDF Box](http://pdfbox.apache.org/) to parse PDF in your project.

Answer (score 1):

Other options include [Apache Tika](http://tika.apache.org/) which supports pdf and other formats and [iText](http://itextpdf.com/).

To use with Groovy/Grails use the Java below as you would with Groovy/Grails

To use Apache tika with Java you would have to:

- download the tika-app-1.2.jar from [tika.apache.org](http://tika.apache.org)
- download  [this](http://blog.vigneshwaran.in/java-program-using-apache-tika-to-extract-tex) sample program
- compile the program with javac -cp tika-app-1.2.jar TextExtractor.java
- Extract some text java -cp tika-app-1.2.jar:. TextExtractor aPDFFile.pdf

To use itext with Java you would:

- download itextpdf-5.3.5.jar
- compile the following:

  ```
  import java.io.IOException;

  import com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfReader;
  import com.itextpdf.text.pdf.parser.PdfTextExtractor;

  public class itextHelloWorld {


     static void extract(String input) throws IOException{
         String path = input;
         PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(path);
         int numberOfPages = reader.getNumberOfPages();
         for (int i = 0;i<numberOfPages;i++) {
             System.out.println(PdfTextExtractor.getTextFromPage(reader,i+1));
         }
     } 

      public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
          extract(args[0]);
      }
  }
  ```
- extract text with java -cp itextpdf-5.3.5.jar:. itextHelloWorld aPDFFile.pdf

Comment: That I do not know how to do as the formatting information is lost with the methods I posted for extracting pdf data.  Maybe you could post a follow up Stack Overflow question to see how to best accomplish what you ask.

Answer (score 0):

Just as another option, I've always had success with [Aspose](http://www.aspose.com/java/pdf-component.aspx) products for such things.  I have no relationship with Aspose in any way.  I just like their products.